# ASP Web.config Internationalization fr-FR currency shows dollar sign

Tags: c#, asp.net, internationalization

I am running into issues setting the globalization settings for a .NET app using the web.config.

```
<globalization culture="fr-FR" uiCulture="fr-FR" />
```

String currency numbers aren't displaying correctly.  They are still using dollar instead of euro signs.  When I change the culture/uiCulture to `en-GB`, they change accordingly.

We are targeting .NET Framework 4.5.2.

Is there something I am missing with the `fr-FR` culture?

Comment: What version of the .net framework are you targeting?

Comment: 4.5.2.. updated the question too.  Not sure why the en-GB works and not the fr-FR.  We will be adding translation files later, but as far as those are concerned, I haven't seen currency symbol changes.

Comment: `string.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR"), "{0:C}", 45.32)` returns a euro sign on .NET Framework 4.5.2 (at least on Windows 10). Are you sure your thread's culture isn't being hijacked somewhere in your app?

Comment: Doing that except without the new `CultureInfo`.  Using the current thread culture (should be set by the globalization tag in web.config) and whenever a background would hijack it, it gets overwritten with the web.config culture. It changes $ to £ when set to `en-GB`, but won't set ­€ for `fr-FR`.